# admob-plus-cordova stopped working on Android

Tags: ionic-framework, admob, admob-rewardedvideoad, firebase-admob, cordova-admob

I use admob-plus-cordova@1.23.1 for a while and everything worked perfectly fine for me.

**All with a simple implementation like this:**

```
this.platform.ready().then(async () => {
       await this.admob.start().then(() => {
            console.log('admob started');
       })

       const rewarded = new this.admob.RewardedAd({
            adUnitId: '<id>',
       })

      await rewarded.load()
      await rewarded.show()
    });
});
```

**in AdMob.java:**

```
Log.i(TAG, "Initializing...");  // This is called
MobileAds.initialize(cordova.getActivity(), status -> {
      Log.i(TAG, "Initialized"); // This is not! since 9th Nov.
      helper.configForTestLab();
      callbackContext.success(new JSONObject(new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
           // Not called since 9th Nov.
      }}));
```

On iOS everything works fine.
But it stopped working on Android a week ago, the implementation or configuration hasn't changed.

But on Android "console.log('admob started');" isn't happening anymore...

Only: "2021-11-17 D/AdMobPlus: Execute start"

**For AdMob:**

1. The App is verified.
2. The app-ads.txt is correct.
3. No messages in the policy center.
4. The review phase is passed.
5. I had a working eCPM floor active, but disabled it 24h ago to be sure, that's not the problem.

Any further ideas?

Thank you!

PS: I already tried updating or downgrading the plugin, no difference.

Probably related to:
https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/zMshI4tmAwc

Comment: I finally got an answer from the Google SDK Team:

"We've received the same issue reported by other publishers as well, and the team is now investigating this. We'll let you know the soonest we have our findings."

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem lies with Google because since a few days it magically works again.